# Moving file pointer back to string it already read

Tags: c

I am trying to find specific word from a file and replace it with some other word.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    FILE *fr;
    fpos_t pos;

    char temp[20];

    fr = fopen("filename_to_open","r+");

    while(!feof(fr)) {
        fgetpos(fr , &pos);
        fscanf(fr, "%s", temp);
        if(strcmp(temp,"word_to_find") == 0) {
            fsetpos(fr, &pos);
            fprintf(fr, "word_to_replace_with");
        }
    }
}
```

After reading an string i am comparing it with an string. if it matches i want to replace it. I tried using fgetpos(), fputpos(), fseek(). i am not getting the desired output. how can i move filepointer back to exactly point it to string it already have read.

Comment: Unless your replacement word is the same length as the original word, you're going to have to shift everything after it as well.

Comment: "I am not getting the desired output". Can you show a short example of what you want to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: Unless you _know_ all words are 19 or less in length, suggest `fscanf(fr, "%19s", temp)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
fseek(fr, -strlen(temp), SEEK_CUR)
```

to move back to the start of the word. So the entire function would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fr;

    char temp[20];

    fr = fopen("file_to_open","r+");

    while(fscanf(fr, "%s", temp) != EOF) {
        if(strcmp(temp,"cat") == 0) {
            fseek(fr, -strlen(temp), SEEK_CUR);
            fprintf(fr, "dog");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As Rob Starling said, this only works if the replacement word is the same length as the original word.

Comment: Note: Better to do `while (fscanf(fr, "%s", temp) != EOF) {` than `while(!feof(fr)) { fscanf(fr, "%s", temp);`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it is working fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
FILE *fr;
fpos_t pos;
int c;
char temp[20];
fr = fopen("filename_to_open","r+");
do {
      fgetpos(fr , &pos);
      c = fscanf(fr,"%s",temp); /* got one word from the file */
      // printf("%s\n",temp);       /* display it on the monitor  */
      if(strcmp(temp,"word_to_find") == 0) {
      fsetpos(fr, &pos);
      fprintf(fr, "word_to_replace_with");
      }
   } while (c != EOF);
}
```

Comment: @chux modified. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a pure `C` example works for you, you may do it while playing with the file pointer as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
    if (!fp)
        return -1;

    char c;
    int len=0;
    while ((c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        len++;
        if (c == '\n') {
            printf("a line detected\r\n");
            fseek(fp, -(len), SEEK_CUR);
            char dat[32];
            fgets(dat, len, fp);
            printf("%s\r\n", dat);
            if (strstr(dat, "20") != NULL) {
                fseek(fp, -len, SEEK_CUR); // rewind to prev
                printf("Found line to delete\r\n");
                fprintf(fp, "%s", "       "); // clear with some patern
                break;
            } else {
                fseek(fp, len+1, SEEK_CUR); // if not matched - go to next
            }
            len = 0; // reset len for next line
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

For example this will replace a line that contains 20 with empty spaces. You need to count the lines also so you know how much you need to rewind forward or backward. You can debug the example and see.