# Fgets does not read from given location

Tags: c

I  want to read a file from a specified location. I have set a file pointer to the particular location (say 400). Now I am running a while loop till end of the file, and I am reading it line by line using fgets. But fgets reads the file from starting, and not from the specified location.

```
fsetpos(src,&pp);
while(!feof(src)) {
     fgets(cpy_buff,sizeof(cpy_buff),src);
     buffsize=strlen(cpy_buff);
     fwrite(cpy_buff, 1,buffsize,dst);
     memset(cpy_buff, 0, sizeof(cpy_buff));
}
```

Comment: Read this:  [**Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: Start by checking the `fsetpos` return value. Is it zero?

Comment: While the refered links are mainly correct, their arguments are in an *"abstract, high-level perspective"*. In fact this is a valid operation and you can use it without any problem in playground code. What is in `pp` before and after the call? Simply print it with a `printf`, or use a debugger.

Comment: How is `pp` initialized? By a `fgetpos` call?

Comment: Maybe you want to check out `fseek` - see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510718/moving-file-pointer-back-to-string-it-already-read I'm pretty sure that `fsetpos` is **not** what you want

Comment: *I have set a file pointer to the particular location (say 400).*  You can't "set" a position for `fsetpos()` in that way.  You can only use it to return to a location and state obtained from `fgetpos()`.  Per [the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.3):  "The `fsetpos` function sets the mbstate_t object (if any) and file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream according to the value of the object pointed to by `pos`, **which shall be a value obtained from an earlier successful call to the fgetpos function on a stream associated with the same file**."

Comment: @peterh *What is in pp before and after the call? Simply print it with a printf, or use a debugger.* Read this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39587990/4756299  The platform isn't specified.  You can't in general `printf()` an `fpos_t` value.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes. We need to suspect as a *work hyphothesis* that it is an integer or similar. It has a quite high chance. If you have some language lawyer affinity, then I would say: the question indirectly states that it is an integer what can contain 400.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oops, I've read your comment just now! You are right. I think it could be a nice answer!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the problem. Your code is way too little to know what is going on.

Comment: @Gerhardh Meanwhile, Andrew Henle has answered it in a comment. This problem does not require MCVE, because it is not a debug problem (even if it looks so), instead it is a C standard api question.

Comment: @peterh While it is very likely that Andrew Henle indeed is right, that comment is based on assumptions about what content might be used in `fsetpos`. A MCVE would show it.